# Mysql workbench update propagation

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've got a web application connected with a mySql db. 
When I do changes to the db through the application (eg. an user insert a sell proposal),  my 'world' is syncronized (every other user can see the proposal, in workbench I can see the proposal in the table).
When a make a change directly on the db, using workbench, there is not a propagation (sort of) and I cannot see the change through the application until minutes/hours or until the next mysql service restart

Any suggestion?

Thank you all

Comment: Did you `commit` your changes in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Yes I've got auto commit Transaction= true. I resolved the issue myself: I had transaction- isolation setted to: READ-UNCOMMITTED so I changed it to READ-COMMITTED and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: in  */etc/mysql/my.cnf* I had transaction-isolation setted to: READ-UNCOMMITTED so I changed it to READ-COMMITTED and it works